# Youtube Data Api Search Endpoint 401 Error

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the Youtube search [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage), which does not seem to require an OAuth token. I've read a few tutorials and they only pass an API key. I'm getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()" error in my console in Chrome Dev Tools. Specifically, looking at the Network tab I get this:

[image]

I notice it says that there is an `error: "invalid_token"` but I pass the api key so they must be talking about the OAuth token? I'm confused because it shouldn't need one, especially because I'm just doing a query for public data. Even the [Try This API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage) portion of the endpoint documentation does not need one. Most importantly, my call in Postman works and just pasting the endpoint in my browser directly works. Why doesn't it work? This is using an axios call from a ReactJS frontend.

```
const apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

const response = await axios.get(url, {
  params: {
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 5,
    q: songName,
    key: apiKey
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What was happening was that I was using      `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =`Bearer ${params.access_token}`;` in other calls for another API. This causes default everything to have this access token! So what I did for now is   `delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];` -- the solution is pretty obvious, just make sure you have no extra headers because Search is not a OAuth endpoint!

Comment: Sorry for intervening, but your statement (quote) *Search is not a OAuth endpoint* is not true. Any YouTube Data API can be accessed with OAuth credentials (i.e. with an access token) when *those credentials are valid* (i.e. *when the [access token has not expired](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline)*).

Comment: For to convince yourself about the truthfulness of my claim above, please issue the following command at a `bash` command line prompt: `wget -qO- --content-on-error --header="Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=Control%20me%20Colde"`. You'll obtain a valid [JSON response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response) containing only one item (mine was a video having the ID `Rf-ctwR7P-M`). Note that the environment variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` has to be set to a valid (non-expired) access token.

Comment: Also note that the access token `$ACCESS_TOKEN` (passed on to the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint) has to be bound to a Google project (created through Google's developers console) that has enabled the YouTube Data API.